# Qt 'Stop Music Button'

Tags: c++, qt, exit, restart

I'm using QT to make an easy game for the university - it' all Ok but :

**First**
I got an Exit button that can quit the game, but it doesn't stop the music (and I want it to do that)

```
// create the quit button
Button* quitButton = new Button(QString("Esci"));
int qxPos = 600;
int qyPos = 0;
quitButton->setPos(qxPos,qyPos);
connect(quitButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
scene->addItem(quitButton);
```

**Second**
I have a restart button and all things go well but when I push it, a new game starts ( enemies spawn , player can move , but the counter of  LIFE and SCORE are frozen    on   3 (total amount of Hp) and 0 (starting score))

Comment: is the code of the button all from ur mainwindow?

Comment: Need more info, especially what is the type of `this` and `scene`? Is `close()` a slot from Qt class or your own slot? When you quit your game, does the process still running in background? How do you implement `restart()`?

Comment: "This" is a Qt class that select  the running program and end it with   " close()"   ,  the code of the button is in an other . cpp called      "gameOver"      when i use the command   close() there is no background program going on except for the gameoverWindow   ... anyway i share you the link of the entire progrram   ( i'm getting really frustrated by thoose 2 bugs )  .   https://mega.nz/#F!tMRU2RLS   THANKS TO ALL

Comment: there is no decripting code , so just press decritt

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1JdjxuSMsYQWVV2ZnpDNXg5bWM&usp=sharing      other way u can find it here